# How do I groupby and divide each value of the group by the number of rows in that group in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
  var df = Seq(("Steve",1),("Steve",0),("Steve",0),("Michael",3),("Michael",2),("Michael",0),("Katherine",4),("Katherine",0),("Devin",0)).toDF("name","score")
  df.show
```

[image]

I want to groupby name, get the number of scores that are equal to 0, and divide that number by the total size of the group.

So it should return 2/3 for the "Steve" group, 1/3 for the "Michael" group, 1/2 for the "Katherine" group, and 1/1 for the "Devin" group.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("zero", when($"score" > 0, 0).otherwise(1))
  .groupBy("name")
  .agg((sum("zero") / count("name")).as("zero_avg") )
df1.show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+------------------+
|     name|          zero_avg|
+---------+------------------+
|    Steve|0.6666666666666666|
|  Michael|0.3333333333333333|
|    Devin|               1.0|
|Katherine|               0.5|
+---------+------------------+
```